# how can i run Webservice code in Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, server, handler

I wanna get some data from server with this code :

```
public class Webservice {

    public static String readUrl(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

            if (params != null) {
                method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);

            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

            return result;
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

but there is some delay and pause in the application , so i wanna run this code in the Thread , but when i tried to do it , i got some error , for example i couldn't return the result or ...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html):

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this
>   from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations
>   on a separate thread from the UI. The AsyncTask class provides one of
>   the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread. For more
>   discussion of this topic, see the blog post Multithreading For
>   Performance.
>
> In the following snippet, the myClickHandler() method invokes new
>   DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl). The DownloadWebpageTask
>   class is a subclass of AsyncTask.
>
> ```
> public class HttpExampleActivity extends Activity {
> private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
> private EditText urlText;
> private TextView textView;
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);   
>     urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
>     textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
> }
>
> // When user clicks button, calls AsyncTask.
> // Before attempting to fetch the URL, makes sure that there is a network connection.
> public void myClickHandler(View view) {
>     // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
>     String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
>     ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
>         getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>     NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
>     if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
>         new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
>     } else {
>         textView.setText("No network connection available.");
>     }
> }
>
>  // Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task takes a 
>  // URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the connection
>  // has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage as
>  // an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string, which is
>  // displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
>  private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
>
>         // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
>         try {
>             return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
>         }
>     }
>     // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         textView.setText(result);
>    }
> }
> ... }
> ```

Comment: take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294533/passing-parameters-to-asynctask  question